# React Native testing with jest failed unexpected token ")"

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

**PROBLEM:** 
I'm just trying a simple use case for React Native with jest and it gave me error "unexpected token ) ". I have successfully eliminate that error but when i run "npm test" the same error will occur but this time it will be on a different files and the cycle continues.

// setup.js
[image]

//__ tests __/loginScreen.js
[image]

Comment: This just means that you have a syntax error. Mostly you forgot to import something or have to many (or less) opening/closing brackets. If you can't fix the errors, you should first learn the syntax of the programming language.

Comment: Those errors were not made by me, i'm guessing there's a problem with the babel compiler, thanks anyway